# How to enable Xorg for user on server?

Tags: xorg, xserver

I have a Shell script on a server. The script is run by a particular user, not root.

The script has the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:8
Xorg $DISPLAY
```

But there is an error:

> Fatal server error:
>   PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
>       Perhaps you do not have console ownership?

Can anyone guide me on how to fix this? I've been Googling but there are numerous different answers so I need a bit of guidance.

Thanks for your time.

Edit: I have found this ([enter link description here](https://lists.sdsc.edu/pipermail/npaci-rocks-discussion/2004-December/008837.html)) which suggests changing the /etc/pam.d/xserver file but I don't really know if that's the right thing to do?

Comment: Why do you want to start an X server from an ssh session? If you want to use X11 clients, use `ssh -X` and make sure you have Apple's X11 or `XQuartz` installed.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I described the actual problem well enough, I've updated my question.

Comment: Where do you want things to be displayed? On your screen or somewhere directly on the server?

Comment: I don't actually need to see anything. I am using something called WebDriver to open Firefox to do some automated UI testing.

Comment: -x- deleted -x-

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver is really not supposed to be run on a server -- It should be run on a workstation being used to conduct the tests.

If you really want to run the WebDriver test suite on the server then as SvenW pointed out, you're *Doing It Wrong*™ – You can't just launch an X server on whatever machine you feel like, especially if you're not on the console (that's the `Perhaps you do not have console ownership?` part of the error message).

The easiest solution in your case is to run an X server on the machine you're SSHing in from, and use `ssh -X` to forward X clients (like Firefox) requests from the server back to your workstation.

Remove the `export DISPLAY=:8` and `Xorg $DISPLAY` lines from the script when you do this.
`ssh -X` will automatically set the `DISPLAY` environment variable for you.

---

Note that there are other possible solutions ("dummy" X servers that don't display anywhere), but that's getting far more complicated than you need to be at this point.